# Need help parsing JSON structure using jq in Terminal

Tags: arrays, json, dictionary, nested, jq

I have a JSON code in the following format, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to use JQ to call information from the nested dictionaries within the objects within the list - if that makes sense. The list is the entire Value of the highest dictionary. Here is a sample of the structure:

```
{ "product" : [ { "A_key1" : "valueA1",
                  "A_key2" : "valueA2",
                  "A_key3" : {"keyA3x_nested" : "valueA3x_nested", "keyA3y_nested" : "valueA3y_nested"}
                 },
                { "B_key1" : "valueB1",
                  "B_key2" : "valueB2",
                  "B_key3" : {"keyB3x_nested" : "valueB3x_nested", "keyB3y_nested" : "valueB3y_nested"}
                 },
              ]
}
```

What I'm trying to do is select only some items from different positions within the hierarchy as follows:

{ "product": { "A_key1": "valueA1", "A_key3": {"keyA3y_nested": "valueA3y_nested"} "B_key1": "valueB1", "B_key3": {"keyB3y_nested": "valueB3y_nested"} } }

So far, I am able to do this on the command prompt:
curl https://sample_api | jq '{product : .product[0]}'

^ That returns the entire object for "A" which includes all 3 of A's keys, but how do I just pull information selectively from lower in the hierarchy?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code should work for you:

```sh
curl https://sample_api | \
jq -r '(.product[0] | .A_key1, .A_key3.keyA3y_nested),
       (.product[1] | .B_key1, .B_key3.keyB3y_nested)'
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great. One other question: how should I call a Key's Value, like valueA3y_nested for example, if that Key has a hyphen in it? I have a Key called "product-category" in the actual API, but when I enter the "-" it doesn't work.

Comment: Just enclose the key name in double quotes: .A_key3."product-category"

Answer (score 0):

Hope this achieves what you are expecting :

```
#!/bin/bash 
                  
jq '. as $root | null '"$(jq -nr '
def spread_paths($array):
    reduce $array[] as $element ([];
        . + (if ($element|type) == "object"
             then ($element | to_entries | map(.key + spread_paths(.value)[]) )
             else [$element] end)
        );
spread_paths([   
   {".product[0].": ["A_key1", "A_key3.keyA3y_nested"]},
   {".product[1].": ["B_key1", "B_key3.keyB3y_nested"]}
])[] | "|\(.)=$root\(.)"
   ') | map_values(.|add)" input-file
```